# How to close a phalcon database connection?

Tags: php, phalcon

I created a `connection` in order to insert data and return the last inserted id of the autoincrement column :

```
function add($tab) {

        $champs= "";
        $value = "";
        $separateur ="";

        $tab["commande_date"] = convertDateFormat5($tab["commande_date"]);

        foreach ($tab as $k => $v){
            if ($k == "salle_code" || $k == "table_code")
                continue;
            $champs .= $separateur . $k;
            $value .= $separateur . "'" . $v . "'";
            $separateur = ",";
        }
        $champs = '('.$champs.')';
        $value = '('.$value.')';

        $sSQL = "INSERT INTO Commande $champs VALUES $value";

        $config = array(
                        "host" => "localhost",
                        "dbname" => BDD,
                        "port" => 3306,
                        "username" => "root",
                        "password" => ""
                        );

        $connection = new \Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql($config);
        $success = $connection->execute($sSQL);
        $id = $connection->lastInsertId();
        return $id;

    }
```

The `connection` is still open at the end of this function , so how to close it ?

Comment: $connection->close(); ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the docs:

> Phalcon automatically closes and destroys active connections when the request ends.

If you really need to close the connection before that happens, your PdoAdapter should provide a `close()` method.